# Pine script function clarification

Tags: function, pine-script

I'm new to pine script and need community help to understand below function, for example passing function returned value again to function as a `series[float]`,

```
momentum(seria, length) =>
    mom = seria - seria[length]
    mom

mom0 = momentum(close, 12)
mom1 = momentum( mom0, 1)
```

1. `mom0` is `float` or `series[float]`?
2. If `mom0` is `series[float]` how? and what kind of data it `series[float]` contains?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mom0` is of type `series float`. Once a `series`, always a `series`.

`mom0` is the momentum based on `close` price. `mom1` is the same but it uses `mom0` as its source.

`mom1` is basically `mom0 - mom0[1]` because `length = 1`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to Answer, please can I know, how ```mom0[1] ``` is calculated?

Comment: `mom0[1]` is `mom0`'s previous value (one bar ago).